# Can't run redis-node-client test code

Tags: node.js, redis

I downloaded node.js (.3), redis (2.0.4), and redis-node-client (git clone).  When I start the redis server in one window, then go to the node-client folder and run

```
node test/test.js
```

I get

```
........................................
node.js:66
      throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
  ^
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I'm using the default configs at the moment. Haven't changed anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, turns out to be version incompatibilities.  Going to v0.2.5 fixes it.

Edit: nevermind, no it doesn't.  Comes up with new error:

```
AssertionError: "testZINTER"  "ERR unknown command 'zinter'"
    at /Users/vhwanger/Dropbox/Programming/nodejs/redis-node-client/test/test.js:121:25
    at Client.onReply_ (/Users/vhwanger/Dropbox/Programming/nodejs/redis-node-client/lib/redis-client.js:400:34)
    at /Users/vhwanger/Dropbox/Programming/nodejs/redis-node-client/lib/redis-client.js:143:30
    at ReplyParser.feed (/Users/vhwanger/Dropbox/Programming/nodejs/redis-node-client/lib/redis-client.js:160:55)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/vhwanger/Dropbox/Programming/nodejs/redis-node-client/lib/redis-client.js:337:28)
    at Stream.emit (events:27:15)
    at IOWatcher.callback (net:489:16)
    at node.js:773:9
```

Comment: Don't pull 0.3.x master unless you know what you get.  e.g. ATM there's no HTTPS support due to ongoing re-implementation of the TLS stuff, and many other breaking things. 0.2.x is stable, 0.3.x is not even bleeding edge it's more like pulling Ryan working dir ;D

Comment: Suggest checking node_redis which is faster :)

Comment: Like shripad said node_redis is better(faster, better maintained, package system)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, redis-node-client is no longer maintained.  That's why I've written node_redis, which you can get with:

```
npm install redis
```

There are a lot of people using it now, and this has helped us work out a lot of bugs. Let me know if you have any issues with it.